# Is 35%=0.35 not as a percentage of a number but just on its own?

Tags: percentages

I was having a disagreement with a number of people commenting on a [Daily Mail story](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-4861562/Could-grammar-school.html?offset=47&max=100&jumpTo=comment-238234026&reply=238234026&ito=rcreplyemail#comment-238234026) and I got a few red arrows indicating disapproval to my comment that 35% is not a number but a proportion and that it is not 0.35 unless we are talking about 35% of 1. This derived from the following purported test question:

> Arrange the following numbers from the smallest to largest:
>   a) 1/3
>   b) 0.305
>   c) 35%
>   d) 3/10

I argued that 35% is not a number but rather a proportion.

Not referencing the above test question but in general, is 35%=0.35 (not 35% of x but just 35% by its own)?

Comment: x% is defined as x*1/100

Comment: This is interesting. $35\%$ does depend on what it is a percentage of, as you say. So $35\%$ could be $0.35$ or $35$ if we are looking at a percentage of $1$ or $100$, respectively. However, without any context as to what the percentage is of, as in the context of the question highlighted (in yellow) above, it means that $35\%$ is a percentage of $1$, so it would be considered $0.35$.

Comment: The fact that a percentage is really just a number divided by 100 became extremely clear to me when taking probability. Being able to say that "A happens with probability $0.5$" is a bit of an eye opener. We commonly use percentage to indicate a proportion like you said, but we also commonly use percentages in such a way that has nothing to do with proportions.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol [%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign) means "per cent".  In this case, "cent" means $100$, so % means $/100$.

35% means $35/100$ or $0.35$.

We often multiply percents by other quantities, like 80% of 200.  Here, "of" designates multiplication.  In the Daily Mail story there is no "of", so no multiplication and no ambiguity.

Comment: But what if there are 35 people selected from 100? That's not 0.35.

Comment: @freethinker36, 35 people selected from 100 is 35% OF the total people.  When a percentage is OF something, then we multiply.  However a percentage can have meaning by itself, as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, a percent is a number just like the others.

So $35\% = 0.35$; it's the largest of the four.